# Why isn't `control_auth_cookie` being created?

Tags: ubuntu, authentication

On Ubuntu, how come Tor (0.2.4.20-1) doesn't create `control_auth_cookie` anywhere on the system after enabling `CookieAuthentication` in `/etc/tor/torrc`?

```
# /etc/init.d/tor start
* Starting tor daemon...                                             [ OK ]
# tail -n 2 /var/log/tor/log
Nov 24 14:09:06.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Nov 24 14:09:06.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done.
# grep "\(DataD\|Cook\)" /etc/tor/torrc
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
CookieAuthentication 1
```

Comment: What makes you think it hasn't? Where did you look for the cookie? How did you enable `CookieAuthentication` (what value did you set it to)?

Comment: I did a `find / -name "control_auth_cookie"`. I enabled it by uncommenting `CookieAuthentication 1`.

Comment: Could you edit your post and insert the output of `grep "\(DataD\|Cook\)" /etc/tor/torrc`?

Comment: @JensKubieziel all done!

Comment: So there should be a file in `/var/lib/tor/control_auth_cookie`. I tested it locally and it worked fine. Has the logfile some hints if something went wrong?

Comment: @JensKubieziel, nope, all is good according to `/var/log/tor/log` here on Debian.

Comment: Try this, worked for me. CookieAuthFile /tmp/control_auth_cookie

Answer (score 1):

Your Tor is probably under the impression that it has already created one. (Maybe it did and you deleted it?)
Try the following:

- Edit your `torrc` to set `CookieAuthentication` to 0
- reset your Tor (kill -HUP or hit `x` twice in Arm)
- Edit your `torrc` again to set `CookieAuthentication` back to 1
- reset your Tor again.

You should now have a new control cookie.

Make sure you have a `ControlListenAddress` and/or `ControlPort` set.

Comment: Tried again with Debian this time. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the package from `universe/net`, the `/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc` file overrides the cookie location to `/var/run/tor/control.authcookie`. You should be able to find it there, or you can override that setting by adding the following line to `/etc/tor/torrc`:

```
CookieAuthFile /var/lib/tor/control_auth_cookie
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably did create the file, but the permissions are set badly by the default tor process when it creates it.

Meaning, it's not readable to you.

On my installation, tor:

1) creates the file with 600, owned by tor:tor

2) the /var/lib/tor/ folder is 700, owned by tor:tor

So, even if the user I login with is in the tor group; the folder is still inaccessible, and the file is invisible/unreadable.

I have to manually alter these to sensible values (640 and 750, respectively) every time the tor daemon reloads (because it resets them back to stupid every time), in order for anything I run to use the control port.

Both permissions failures have to be manually fixed every single time...

Herp derp...

Comment: *cough* `CookieAuthFileGroupReadable` *cough*

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Tor#Set_a_Tor_Control_cookie_file for more info on `CookieAuthFileGroupReadable`